# How do I go about filtering leads from Facebook Graph API based on the created_date

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I'm using the Graph API Explorer tool to get lead response details but because I'm doing it as a batch/bulk query I'm getting 100s of results back.

Is there a way to filter the results to only bring back responses from the last 7 days (for example).

Below is the code that I've tried - which is supposed to return responses greater than 19/06/2019 00:00 (using unix timestamp) - but it just seems to ignore the filter a brings back everything.

```
page_id?fields=leadgen_forms{leads{form_id,ad_id,ad_name,platform,created_time,field_data,custom_disclaimer_responses,retailer_item_id}}&filtering=[{"field":"leadgen_forms{leads{created_time}}","operator":"GREATER_THAN","value":1560902400}]
```

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/leadgen_forms/ doesn’t mention any filtering. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/lead-ads/retrieving does, but that is a completely different endpoint than the one you are currently using.

Comment: try use the field `time_created`instead of  `created_time `